# Retrieve a hidden value of a dialog box of jquery to a HTML div

Tags: jquery, html

I have two radio buttons while clicking on a radio button a jquery dialog box pops up using the dialog api of jquery , where i am having a hidden field in the dialog box, so now i require the hidden value to the background html in a div tag (in the page ) where the radio buttons are present .

HTML Code:

```
<input type="radio" class="f_auth" name="f_auth_type" value="a"/>A
<input type="radio" class="f_auth" name="f_auth_type" value="b" />B

OnClicking of radio button 'A' my dialog box pops up in which through a jquery call to separate file from this dialog box, as  i am saving the response in a hidden field in the dialog box , so now i want that value of the hidden file in the background html

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="chk"/>
</div>
<div id="display1"></div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
var button_val = $("input[name='f_auth_type']:checked").val();
if(button_val == "A") {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
}
else {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
}

$('#dialog').dialog({
              modal: 'true',
              title: 'Train a Form',
              height: 550,
              width: 450,
              buttons:
                    {
                 Ok: function() {               
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             },
             Cancel: function() {       
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             }
            },
                });
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far, javascript and html.

Comment: Not too clear on what your question is. Are you trying to place the value of your dialog box (assuming there's an input) to be shown in a div in your background html?

Comment: Now you can check the piece of code that i have attached

Comment: @shrmn yes the same thing i want what you had posted just now.

Comment: @Esa now you can find the piece of code attached

Comment: Sorry, this confuses me more. Are you trying to make the radio button select when the user presses Ok and de-select when the user presses Cancel?

Comment: @shrmn now u can find more in detail (in Question)